# Is it a proper usage for 'a top of'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am currently working with writing so-called 'fancy' English sentences, and here is one of such samples:

> Of course, moi knew about that ring **atop of the** other rubbish thou acquired!

A 'normal' translation I am going for would be something like following:

> Of course I knew you got that ring **in addition to** the rest of the junk you purchased!

Can I use **atop of** as a meaning "in addition to"? Or should I try rephrasing it completely?

Comment: Just FYI,  *moi* is not "fancy" English- it's French and is really out of place in your sentence.  Your use of *thou* is haphazard. It's doubtful your sentence achieves what you were hoping for.

Comment: I'm also much more accustomed to seeing *atop* without *of* : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atop+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Catop%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Batop%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Batop%20its%3B%2Cc0)   "atop the other rubbish you acquired"  (Kipling's notwithstanding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the figurative meaning of ***[on top of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-top-of)***  is:

> in addition to
>
> - on top of his accident, he caught pneumonia

(Collins Dictionary)

***[Atop of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/atop)***  is a less common, literary variant:

From [Letters of Rudyard Kipling](https://books.google.it/books?id=Bf5aAAAAMAAJ&q=%22atop%20of%22&dq=%22atop%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih8tSi-qbdAhUS_qQKHeSKATA4ChDoAQgwMAM):

> ***And, atop of all this,*** there is the doyen of the British Community who looks in to give one advice from time to time, and to show one the way in which to walk, socially.